# nginx возвращает 502 Bad Gateway даже если приложение уже работает

Tags: nginx, erlang

На сервере настроена связка Nginx + Erlang. А именно - nginx слушает 80-й порт и проксирует запросы на порт 8738. Erlang с помощью Cowboy, принимает запросы с порта 8738 и отдаёт статику по http или обрабатывает сообщения по WebSocket. Вот кусок конфига, который за это отвечает:

```
# При запросе страниц бэковой части перебрасываем на эрланг
location /back {
    # настройки проксирования на эрланг
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8738/back;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;                        # без особой надобности
    proxy_cache_valid 502 10s;                          # недолго кешируем ошибку "502 Bad Gateway", если эрланг ещё не запустился
    # всё что ниже нужно для работы вебсокетов
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;             # передаём заголовок "Upgrade: websocket", если он пришел от клиента
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;    # добавляем заголовок "Connection: Upgrade", если был передан заголовок "Upgrade: websocket"
}
```

Это была предыстория. Вообще сейчас не важно что такое Erlang, Cowboy и WebSocket.
**Проблема вот в чём**:

После перезагрузки сервера получается так, что nginx стартует раньше чем erlang. Соответственно, nginx не видит ничего на порту 8738 и возвращает 502 Bad Gateway. Да вроде бы и норм, но когда erlang запускается, ситуация остаётся неизменной. Ошибка 502 так и будет возвращаться всегда.
В логах nginx вот это:

```
2017/06/02 12:07:33 [error] 708#708: *899 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: foobar.com.ua, request: "GET /back HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8738/back", host: "foobar.com.ua"
```

**Hotfix**: просто сделать `sudo nginx -s reload` и сразу всё работает! Работает сколько угодно времени до первой перезагрузки.

Как побороть это?

Comment: 1. в конфигурации у вас больше нигде не упоминается `proxy_cache_valid`? 2. попробуйте убрать эту директиву. что изменится? 3. сколько именно времени вы ждали вместо «всегда»? 4. когда nginx возвращает ошибку, а cowboy работает, к нему получается обратиться локально напрямую, без nginx-а? 5. строка в логе добавляется при каждом обращении к nginx-у?

Comment: 1. `proxy_cache_valid` больше нигде нету. 2. раньше её и не было. Я добавил в надежде, что что-то изменится, но эффекта не дало. 3. «всегда» - к примеру два дня. 4 и 5 - проверю, отпишусь.

Comment: 4. да, когда nginx возвращает ошибку, запрос `curl http://127.0.0.1:8738/back` без проблем возвращает статическую страницу напрямую от ковбоя. 5. да, строка в логе добавляется при каждом обращении к nginx-у.

Comment: 1. попробуйте подменить cowboy+erlang [мини-сервером](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16640054/4827341), для того, чтобы убедиться точно, что проблема именно на стороне nginx-а. 2. ну и так, на всякий случай, попробуйте использовать другой порт.

Comment: 1. попробовал подменить мини-сервером - результат абсолютно тот же. 2. поменял порт на 32913 - результат абсолютно тот же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что nginx при загрузке резолвит localhost в IPv6 адрес, а ваш сервер слушает на IPv4 адресе. После перезагрузки конфига nginx повторно резолвит адрес и на этот раз резолвит IPv4 адрес.

Если Cowboy слушает на всех портах, то можно в настройках systemd указать nginx что бы он стартовал только после запуска Cowboy.

Comment: "указать nginx что бы он стартовал только после запуска Cowboy" - это самый нежелательный вариант. А если приложения на эрланге вообще не будет (надоело, удалил), тогда nginx никогда не запустится? Да и вообще хотелось бы поменьше менять системные настройки.

Comment: А можно как-то заставить nginx не работать с IPv6 адресами в командах proxy_pass?

Comment: @Pavel можно прямо прописать 127.0.0.1 вместо localhost

Comment: да, это оно! Работает!!! Спасибо.

Comment: Подведу итог. У меня в конфиге nginx перенаправление запроса на эрланг было указано вот таким образом: `proxy_pass http://localhost:8738/back;`. Эта директива указывает как на IPv4 адрес (127.0.0.1), так и на IPv6 адрес. Nginx искал ещё не запустившееся эрланг-приложение сначала на IPv4 адресе, а затем на IPv6. Не находил ничего и продолжал отправлять запросы только на IPv6 адрес. Когда эрланг запускался, он слушал только IPv4 адрес. Решением проблемы стало изменить строку `proxy_pass http://localhost:8738/back;` на `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8738/back;`, то есть явно указать IPv4 адрес.

Comment: @AlexanderT, не «скорее всего», а точно. в приведённой строке из лога фигурирует то, что и автор вопроса и я проглядели: `upstream: "http://[::1]:8738/back"`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я не знал настроек сервера, потому не мог утверждать точно. :)